# Async does not seem to wait for await

Tags: node.js

I use node js and postgres as well as chai and mocha for tdd, and now I have encountered a problem when I try to update an item in my database with a wrong foreign key. When this happens I want to basically get the old item from the database with the valid values.

this is the update method in the Item class

```
async update() {
        if (this.description.length === 0) {
            throw new Error("Description can not be deleted");
        }
        try {
            const updateItem = await this.tryUpdate();
            this.copyToThis(updateItem);
        } catch (e) {
            const oldItem = await Item.getById(this.id);
            this.copyToThis(oldItem);

            console.log(this);

            throw new Error("Updating did not work");
        }
    }
```

This is the test that fails

```
it('should throw an error if you update with wrong category or project id and get the old values from the server', async function () {
            const newProject = "3b4e092e-1dd9-40a5-8357-69696b3e35ba";
            const newCategory = "3cf87368-9499-4af1-9af0-10ccf1e84088";
            const item = await Item.getById(updateId);
            expect(item).to.exist;

            const oldProjectId = item.projectId;
            const oldCategoryId = item.categoryId;

            item.projectId = newProject;
            expect(item.update()).to.be.rejectedWith(Error);

            item.categoryId = newCategory;
            expect(item.update()).to.be.rejectedWith(Error);

            expect(item.categoryId).to.equal(oldCategoryId);
            expect(item.projectId).to.equal(oldProjectId);
        });
```

this is the AssertionError

```
 -3cf87368-9499-4af1-9af0-10ccf1e84088
 +3cf87368-9499-4af1-9af0-10ccf1e84087
```

As you can see the item still has the wrong categoryId and not the one from the server. Eventhough the log has the correct item.

Comment: You're changing the object category and project a couple of lines before? if u want to really test if the update has failed you need to read the item from the database again.

Comment: In the update methode I read the item from the database again with the `await Item.getById(this.id)`. Therefore it should have to the old item. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: your doing this `item.projectId = newProject;` and it changes the item fields event if the update fails.

Comment: But this happens before I call `item.update()` and in update it should get the old values from the server if goes in the catch block

Comment: yes but you are not waiting for the update in the expect

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself

I needed to add an await in the test

```
it('should throw an error if you update with wrong category or project id and get the old values from the server', async function () {
            const newProject = "3b4e092e-1dd9-40a5-8357-69696b3e35ba";
            const newCategory = "3cf87368-9499-4af1-9af0-10ccf1e84088";
            const item = await Item.getById(updateId);
            expect(item).to.exist;

            const oldProjectId = item.projectId;
            const oldCategoryId = item.categoryId;

            item.projectId = newProject;
            await expect(item.update()).to.be.rejectedWith(Error);

            item.categoryId = newCategory;
            await expect(item.update()).to.be.rejectedWith(Error);

            expect(item.categoryId).to.equal(oldCategoryId);
            expect(item.projectId).to.equal(oldProjectId);
        });
```